# UK student visitor visa refused, Erasmus Mundus scholarship

Tags: united-kingdom, study, student-visa

I come from Georgia. I have been selected for the Erasmus Mundus master's programme and received a scholarship of 42.000 EUR. This is a very prestigious scholarship scheme and a very reliable source of funding.

The programme starts on September 1st and I must spend the 1st semester at the University of Cumbria, Ambleside, the UK. In January 2016, I must move to Norway in order to continue my studies at the Norwegian Institution. From August 2016, I must study in Germany for the next part of my programme.

I have applied to the UK Visas and Immigration office, Istanbul. I have asked for short term student visitor visa and got refused. Now I am reapplying and have some questions.

Exact wording of the refusal letter quoted here:

> You have applied to visit the UK as part of the Erasmus Mundus Scheme. You have provided evidence from the scheme and from the Universities involved, including the University of Cumbria.
>
> You have stated that you are employed as a manager by COMPANYNAME. It is reasonable that you would provide evidence of this employment to demonstrate your source of income. You have provided a bank letter and statement from AAA Bank and I note the statement shows salary deposits, however the lack of any evidence from your stated employer to corroborate the income raises concerns. I realise you state you are resigning from your employment, however I would still expect to see evidence to show the source of your personal funds.
>
> Your bank letter also states you hold two other accounts, including a Euro account. You have not demonstrated any source for the funds in these accounts.
>
> Although your visit will be funded by the Erasmus Mundus Scheme, it is still reasonable that you would provide evidence of your circumstances in Georgia. The lack of such evidence raises concerns regarding your intentions and reason for travelling to study overseas.
>
> In light of all of the above I am not satisfied as to your intentions in wishing to travel to the UK now. I am not satisfied that you genuinely intend a short student visit only to the UK and that you will leave the UK at the end of the visit. I am therefore not satisfied that your application meets the paragraph A57D(b)

Fist of all, about the evidence from my employer, when I filled in my application, I was about to leave my job because I wanted more time to prepare for my studies. And by the time I had an appointment at Teleperformance, I had already left my job. This is why I didn't even think of retrieving such letter from my employer. Now I see it was stupid of me. For my new application, I have retrieved the letter proving that I indeed worked there from ---- to ---- and received salary of ----. Do you think it helps?

As for two other bank accounts, I have some money on both of them but not so much. This was gift from my father when he heard I was going to study abroad. I didn't know it was necessary to demonstrate this. This time I have retrieved a document from bank that proves that it was indeed my father who deposited this sum to my account. Do you think it helps?

I understand that these two documents were indeed lacking in my application but what is surprising for me is that my personal funds should not be important when I receive a scholarship from Erasmus Mundus. I have enclosed several letters from Erasmus Mundus Scheme itself, from European Union, from my host universities, all stating that ALL MY COSTS WILL BE COVERED BY ERASMUS. I can support myself with this scholarship even without the money that I personally own. I am also surprised because I have a very good travel record in Schengen countries. I have received 4 visas during past 5 years and the last one is a 2-year schengen visa which is still in force.

I have requested more supporting letters from universities and from the Erasmus Mundus Association representatives in Georgia. I hope this also helps.

I am thinking of enclosing frank letter where I will explain why the documents were lacking in the first application and that I am adding them now. I also want to demonstrate in this letter that I do not intend to stay in the UK I perfectly understand that everybody would say the same but the thing is that if I don't leave UK, I cannot go to Norway to continue my studies and my scholarship and everything will be completely lost. This is very logical. It is not in my interests to stay in UK. I also want to indicate that I have amazing parents here at home and I would never want to leave my country forever. I also want to include letters proving that they have well paid jobs here. Do you think it is good?

Last but not the least, should I send the refusal letter back to them with my new application documents?

Comment: Based on [the on-topic definitions in the help centre](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), a stay of just a few months is too short to be asked here, needs to be at least a year. You'd be better off on the [travel.se site](http://travel.stackexchange.com), which handles trips up to a year

Comment: That's what I did initially and they instructed me to post on expatriates. I am confused now.

Comment: If you [hop onto the Travel.SE chat right now](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here), we're currently debating the right site!

Comment: I'd say keep on topic, but created a meta post, whether we want to change our FAQ: [Are questions about studying abroad where the duration is only one term/semester on-topic?](http://meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/260)

Comment: FYI, the [Travel.SE version of this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52695/uk-student-visitor-visa-refused-erasmus-mundus-scholarship) has now been re-opened

Comment: Closing as it's cross-posted, and has been successfully answered on  travel: [UK student visitor visa refused, Erasmus Mundus scholarship](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52695/uk-student-visitor-visa-refused-erasmus-mundus-scholarship)